# User reputation graph uses client date

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation-graph

I found that reputation graph on SO is actually using the client date and not server date(SO server date) to show the reputation.

I was working on some assignment and for that, I changed my system date to last month, after that, when I visited the SO to see my current reputation, it was showing me for the last month only and not for the current month/current date.

When I changed back my system date, graph was working fine again.

I think, the reputation graph should work according to server date and not the client date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm declining this. If you toy around with your system date, you should know what you're doing. Especially in times where most computer clocks are set via NTP anyway, it's reasonable to assume that the user's clock is correct.

In fact the concept of "user changes computer's clock" is *impossible* to fully support (try `setTimeout(function () { alert("done"); }, 10000);` and then set your clock back a month).

But this isn't even only related to JavaScript: Our session cookies are set to expire after six months. And we're certainly not going to change that to accommodate people who play with their system clocks (try logging in to Stack Overflow with your system clock set to more than six months from now* – it ain't gonna work).

So – no. We'll always work on the assumption that the client's time is correct. And actually I consider it pretty far-fetched to call this a "bug".

<sub>* actually don't try it; it'll screw up several of your running programs, as I was just able to confirm :)</sub>