# Logged out, couldn't log back in, when local system time was changed

Tags: support

So, I am not sure if this was by design, or why it really happened. I was looking at my profile on stackoverflow, and decided to change the time on my local machine to see if my age changed on the profile page (out of curiosity). I am on a windows 7 machine, with the current updates, and using chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m.

I changed the date to 2014, then refocused the profile page and hit refresh. I was a little surprised that I was then logged out. Perhaps changing the date caused all of my cookies to expire? I am not sure if this is an issue on stackexchange's side but I figured I would at least point it out.

When trying to log back in, I entered an infinite loop of redirection, which would tell me I was being logged in, redirect, then I would not be logged in, and then tell me I was being logged in, etc. This happened when trying to enter chat and on stackoverflow.

To get logged back in, I had to change the date to 2013, and then close the browser, and restart it. Obviously, I am logged back in now, but I felt like detailing what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" kind of thing. Easy solution. Stop doing that.

If you want to play around with your system clock, expect *a lot* of things to break in one way or the other. Not just our website, but a whole bunch of other things, too.

As to *why* the logout happens, see my answer at [User reputation graph uses client date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134925/user-reputation-graph-uses-client-date/134929#134929)

Comment: At first glance I thought "Doctor" was referring to the [Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who).