# Unable to login for Stack Overflow in Mac OS X 10.8.2 in Firefox

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, login, yahoo

I have a Stack Overflow account, and I want to login into my account using Yahoo-ID. I am using the Firefox browser v. 18.0.2 on [Mac OS X 10.8.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion).

It shows me the login screen correctly and allows me to login. Then it shows me the message:

> Welcome back Vin, you've been logged in. You are being redirected...

(Here "**Vin**" is my profile name.)

The problem is that this message keep refreshing, and it doesn't redirect me.

> [image: http://i.imgur.com/cd8eqJr.png?1]

It doesn't show my username on the screen, and it doesn't allow me to ask the question. I tried to empty the cache, without luck.

- Is this a bug in Firefox, Stack Overflow or some other issue?
- What is the solution for this issue?

Please note: I tried all the ways described in the above link, but it's not working at all.

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : Nope, My REPUTATION is below 10... :(

Comment: Upload it to imgur or something and post the link.

Comment: Check my EDIT , if it is helpful to you !!

Comment: Added Screenshot Link

Comment: Did you [change your computer local time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163152/152859)? If so, change it back.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: But I have never changed my computer local time !!

Comment: OK, just checking. And here on Meta you're using the same Yahoo ID without any problems?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : No, I am using my another (gmail) account.

Comment: @Arjan : I have tried all the ways described in that Thread but still it's not working

Comment: Well, I'm sure you didn't try *all* form [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469) ;-)

Comment: Also: any errors in [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help), and is your clock set correctly?

Comment: @Arjan : I added the Screenshot of Test...and my clock is set correctly.

Comment: Then, @Bhavin, I guess [the *"if that doesn't work"* part](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469) applies.

Comment: And I assume you also have a "Communication with stackauth.com" part in that Login Troubleshooting page?